# How does pummeling work?

Tags: halo-reach

In Halo:Reach, how much damage does a beat-down, or "pummel" do in multiplayer?  At what point can I be guaranteed that a beat-down will kill the opponent?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From my experience, whenever I melee an opponent who doesn't have any shields, the melee always kills them. If you melee when they still have shields, then only their shields are removed (thus taking a max of two melee attacks to kill an opponent).

Edit: The [Bungie Weekly Update](http://www.bungie.net/News/content.aspx?type=topnews&cid=28836) for September 24 has more information about how melee attacks and headshots work in Halo Reach. The basic idea is the same: melee will destroy any remaining shields (and nothing else), while a melee to a shieldless opponent will kill him.

Comment: A Melee attack will always deplete what ever resource they are currently on.

Comment: "Bosses" such as the big guys with the axe or Elites do not die with one pummel.

Comment: That is generally because they have overshields rather than just a single shield layer.  Once an elites shields have popped and they do the rawwwrrrrr animation where they throw their hands up in the air (can't think of how else to describe it) then a single melee should kill them.  Of course they still might melee you first!

Answer (score 2):

Andy's correct, except in game modes where health has been modified.

For example, I believe SWAT modes double spartan health, so even though you do not have shields in SWAT, a single melee attack will still not kill an enemy at full health.  There may be other game modes either now or in the future that change player health percentages, but I can't think of any.

Under any 'normal' game mode, any melee after shields have popped is a kill.

Answer (score 1):

If the opponent has 10% shields (just a rough guess but it has to be pretty low) the melee attack with anything will kill the opposing enemy.